# How can i navigate to another page with re-render page using react router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to navigate to another page and re-render the page by react router V6.
I'm trying:

```
navigate("/anotherPage",0);
```

but it's not work.

```
 window.location.reload(false);
```

doesn't right in my case.

How can i do it?

Comment: There's not enough here to help. Please see [ask]. Why would you want to reload the entire page?

Comment: Reload the page or re-render the page?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito i mean re-render the page

Comment: When the path changes the router, routes, and route necessarily rerender to render the new matched content. You shouldn't need to force anything. This has the smell of an XY problem. What is the *actual* issue you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
location.href = "/anotherPage";
```